# Get the count of distinct values from a Sequence in F#

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a sequence of Country names in F#. I want to get how many of each distinct country entries do I have in the sequence.

The countBy examples in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences#sorting-comparing-and-grouping) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.countby%5B%27t,%27key%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) use `if` and `else` to get the Keys, but since I have ~240 distinct entries, I guess that I don't need to make an elif sentence for each entry, right?

So, is there an option to use another sequence to get the keys for the countBy?

```
#load "packages/FsLab/FsLab.fsx"
open FSharp.Data
open System

type City = JsonProvider<"city.list.json",SampleIsList=true>

let cities = City.GetSamples()

let Countries = seq { for city in cities do yield city.Country.ToString() } |> Seq.sort

let DistinctCountries = Countries |> Seq.distinct

//Something like this
let Count = Seq.countBy DistinctCountries Countries
```

Anyone interested in my [city.list.json](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/)

**Update**

My input sequence is something like this (with a lot more of entries) with each code repeated as many cities for that country are in the original list:

```
{ "AR","AR","AR","MX","MX" }
```

As a result I expect:

```
{("AR", 3),("MX", 2),...}
```

Comment: This question would be clearer if you gave at least one example of an input value and the expected output.

Comment: A simple but **complete** example is always good to have: `{ "AR","MX","AR"}` -> `{("AR", 2),("MX",1)}`. Giving examples like this will get you much better help! It's amazing how many people don't do it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Countries |> Seq.countBy id
```

`id` is the identity function `fun x -> x`. Use this because the "key" here is the sequence item itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can group the countries and then count the number of entries in each group:

```
let countsByCountry = 
  Countries 
  |> Seq.groupBy id 
  |> Seq.map (fun (c, cs) -> c, Seq.length cs)
```

This combination is also implemented as a single function, `countBy`:

```
let countsByCountry = Countries |> Seq.countBy id
```

Answer (score 5):

> So, is there an option to use another sequence to get the keys for the countBy?

You do not need to *get* the keys from somewhere, the function passed to `Seq.countBy` generates the keys. You should be able to get away with this:

```
let count = 
    cities
    |> Seq.countBy (fun c -> c.Country.ToString())
```

Comment: ...or just `cities |> Seq.countBy (fun c -> c.Country.ToString())` - no need for the extra map.

Comment: Even better :) The important point here is to avoid the sequence comprehension and the sort.